# Electrophoretic mobility of isozymes

Tags: molecular-biology, homework

If isozymes are seperated using electrophoresis, which of the following will be the principle of separation ?

A.charge density

B.molecular weight

C.polarity of molecule

I think it should be B.

Comment: What class is this for?

Comment: for general bio class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(B) is incorrect. I think the answer is (C) but to my mind those other two options are badly worded.

Here is an explanation.

The classic example of isozymes is the case of [lactate dehydrogenase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactate_dehydrogenase).

As you will see if you visit the Wikipedia page the enzyme is a tetramer, and there are two subunit types, the *muscle* or M type and the *heart* or H type. Consequently there are 5 isozymes, ranging from M<sub>4</sub> to H<sub>4</sub> with all possible combinations in between. Different tissues express these two subunit types to different degrees and so are characterised by a different pattern of isozymes.

The M type is encoded by the LDHA gene and the H type by the LDHB gene. I obtained the sequences of the two proteins and analysed them:

LDHA: 332 amino acids; 36.7 kD; pI=8.45

LDHB: 334 amino acids; 36.6 kD; pI=5.93

You can see from this that the ability to separate these isozymes depends upon charge and not molecular weight. That big difference in pI (isoelectric point) means that at neutral pH the LDHA protein will carry a net positive charge while the LDHB protein will be negatively charged. Consequently each tetramer will have a unique overall charge. [You can find some details and an image of an electrophoresis result here.](http://www.molvis.org/molvis/v11/a85/acosta-fig3.html)

In general, protein electrophoresis is much more sensitive to charge differences than it is to molecular mass except in the special case of SDS-PAGE when the large amount of negatively-charged detergent that binds to the proteins masks their intrinsic charge differences.

Another classic example of this is the ability to [separate haemoglobin S in sickle cell patients from haemoglobin A in normal blood](https://www.mun.ca/biology/scarr/Hemoglobin_Electrophoresis.html). In this case the only difference between the two molecules is a single Glu>Val substitution in two of the monomers in each tetramer.